# how can i subscribe to a podcast series from itunes on my ipod touch

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I see i can download individual podcasts one by one but i can't figure out how to subscribe to an entire podcast going forward on my ipod touch.

is this possible or can you only do this from itunes on your computer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't subscribe to them from your iTunes app on your iPod.

The easiest way I know of is to subscribe to whatever podcast you want to listen to in your preferred feed reader, and then whenever that podcast is updated you'll see it in your feed. From there you can just choose to play or download it. Hopefully this helps solve your issue.

Comment: is there any logic to this limitation.  It seems like an obvious feature

Comment: @ooo, I think there is just no way to push updates and have iTunes on the iPhone/iPod Touch automatically download them in the background. This is probably to avoid big silent downloads on an iPhone when using 3G and has most probably been replicated on the iPod to keep behaviour the same.

Comment: @ooo I think Neil hit the nail on the head. There are also jailbreak solutions for subscribing if that helps, but I find just subscribing via RSS works for me - easier on an iPhone the iPod though I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't integrate with iTunes, [Instacast](http://vemedio.com/products/instacast) will let you subscribe and download new episodes to podcasts.